# Lower Bound Question

Tags: boundary-value-problem

Assume we have a function like this:
$$
  F(x)
= \sum_{k=1}^x f(k)
$$
And we have upper and lower bounds for it:
$$
  c_1 g(x) 
< F(x)
< c_2h(x).
$$
Can we find a lower bound for $f(x)$ with this information? I tried this but it didn't work.

But $c_1g(x) - c_2h(x-1)$ is always negative for particular $g,h$ functions I'm working on... I need to find a positive lower bound. Is it possible?

Let $\pi$(x) be the prime counting function.

$$g(x) = (\pi(x)-1)^2$$
$$h(x) = (\pi(2x-1)-1)^2$$

Comment: Without more information you cannot be sure that a positive lower bound exists. Is there more information about $f$ or $g$ and $h$ that you can provide?

Comment: Let Pi(x) be the prime counting function.

$$g(x) = (Pi(x)-1)^2$$
$$h(x) = (Pi(2x-1)-1)^2$$